# Adb Shell dumpheap for native not working

Tags: android, debugging, adb, native, heap-dump

I need to take the native dump of the android process. 
The cmd I am using is:

```
adb shell am dumpheap -n <pid> /data/local/tmp/dump.txt
```

The device is S8, Oreo OS.

Everytime I run this cmd, the 'dump.txt' is generated with the following content:

> Native heap dump not available. To enable, run these commands
>   (requires root):$ adb shell setprop libc.debug.malloc 1 $ adb shell
>   stop $ adb shell start

Though I am doing it says and the phone is also rooted but it still gives the same content.

I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I already did it, but same problem occuring.

Comment: Also, after 'adb shell su' cmd; Once I gave 'stop', then 'setprop' and then after that 'start' cmd , it puts the device in bootloop, the gui never shows up.